Number of solutions of $x^7=e$ and of $x^{17^2} = e$ in a group with 2023 elements
I am attempting to solve the following problem.

Let $(G,.)$ be a group with 2023 elements.
Find the number of solutions of the equation:
$x^7 = e$
and the number of solutions of the equation:
$x^{17^2} = e$, where e is the identity element.

2023 factors as 7 * $17^2$.
I found the following theorem mentioned around here, which seems useful, but I have never found a proof of it:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius%27s_theorem_(group_theory)
If someone knows of a proof of this theorem, please post it, or a link to it.

Should $x$ satisfy both equations? Or are these two separate questions? In the title the equation is missing.

@DietrichBurde Thanks for your input. I updated the question.

Where did this question come from? What theorems ahve you learned about group theory and what are you allowed to use? Surely you learned something relevant in your class that would help answer? Anyway this is relevant needed information.

@Mike It's from a math magazine.

A math magazine? Which one?

The Romanian mathematical magazine, number 12/2023, if you've heard of it.

@DietrichBurde It's easy to see using Sylow's Theorem that a group of order $2023$ is necessarily abelian, so there aren't many choices for its structure.

@RobertShore How would you use Syvlov's theorems to prove that a group of order 2023 is abelian. I only know of these theorems: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems

Both Sylow subgroups are normal so the group must be a direct product of its Sylow subgroups.  A group of order 7 is cyclic.  You also need the result that a group of order $p^2$ (for $p$ prime) is always abelian.  That is not a consequence of Sylow's theorems, but it's easy to prove.  However, you don't need that the $17$-Sylow subgroup is abelian to answer the question in the title.
